# The url for logging in to Docusign rest api returns "Could not Resolve Host"

Tags: docusignapi

The url https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information mentioned in the docs gives an error 'could not resolve host'...
https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/usage/quickstart.html#authenticate-and-get-your-base-url
Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are behind a corporate firewall, please ensure that you have appropriate routing & permissions setup to allow connectivity to DocuSign. From that error message it sounds like your request is not leaving your network.